# Django app not including base.html template in downstream apps

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application where I am trying to set up a base html template to include footers, navbars etc which I can re-use across the site.

The issue I am having is that I get an error when I try to include my base template in the downstream app template folders and indexes. I hope that makes sense.

In my main root directory I have `templates/base.html` and in my app at `NewsBase/templates/NewsBase/index.html` I have the below:

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}

<body>
    <h1>NewsBase</h1>
</body>
```

My routes/urls are working fine as this html renders as long as the `extends` block is removed.

How can I properly include my `base.html` template from other apps in the solution?

Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

{%  load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% include "footer.html" %}

</html>
```

Error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
templates/base.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.11.29
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
templates/base.html
Exception Location: /home/etherk1ll/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py in find_template, line 148
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.17
Python Path:    
['/home/etherk1ll/Development/python_projects/NewSite',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/etherk1ll/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 30 Apr 2020 22:30:51 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

if you check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#extends

it states that this:

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}
```

should change to

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

since all the templates are in a `templates` folder.

the same logic for imports is used in the `static` folder and templatetag